# WPF: Binding for ListBox and ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I learn bindings in WPF via book. I have wrote such code:

```
using System;

namespace WpfBinding {
    enum SomeColors {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue,
        Gray
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;

namespace WpfBinding {
    class TestItem {
        SomeColors color;

        public TestItem(SomeColors color) {
            Color = color;
        }
        internal SomeColors Color {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value; }
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return Color.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML of my Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried create binding through code:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfBinding {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Data for listbox
            TestItem[] items = new TestItem[] {
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Green), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Green), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Blue), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
            };
            // Create ObservableCollection item
            ObservableCollection<TestItem> collection = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>(items);
            listBox.ItemsSource = collection;// set data for listbox

            comboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeColors)); // Get items from my enum

            // Create bindings
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Source = listBox;
            bind.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Color");
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
           comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, bind);
        }
    }
}
```

But my binding ain't working. Why?

Screen: 
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "ain't working"?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla I have edited a my message: was added a screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the error -

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property
not found on 'object' ''TestItem' (HashCode=13974362)'.  
BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Color; DataItem='ListBox' (Name='listBox');
target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='comboBox'); target property is 'SelectedItem'
(type 'Object')
```

You need to make the property `Color` `public` instead of `internal`.

From MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) -

> The properties you use as binding source properties for a binding must
>   be public properties of your class. Explicitly defined interface
>   properties cannot be accessed for binding purposes, nor can protected,
>   private, internal, or virtual properties that have no base
>   implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the problem is that your classes are not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

In order for the bindings to know when a property has changed it's value, you have to send it notification, and you do that with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**UPDATE**

So your listbox is bound to an `ObservableCollection` which does provide change notifiations, but *only* to the list box and only if you add or remove items from the collections.

You might also want to enable WPF Binding trace information in visual studio (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that might help you figure out what is going on too.

The last thing I noticed is that the Color property of your `TestItem` class is marked as `internal`.  WPF won't have access to that property unless it's `public`.

Comment: But I using the `ObservableCollection<T>` as source. It is implemented:
`ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: And when I select `TestItem` in listbox, I have changed `ListBox.SelectedItem` property only.

Answer (score 2):

It's always useful to watch the Output window of Visual Studio when debugging! Had you looked there, you'd have seen this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'object' ''TestItem' (HashCode=20856310)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem.Color; DataItem='ListBox' (Name='listBox'); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='comboBox'); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object')
```

Exactly, binding can be done with public properties only, so

```
internal SomeColors Color
```

should be

```
public SomeColors Color
```

Comment: Thank you! Now ComboBox updated, when I select items in ListBox. I edit my code:

`...
            ObservableCollection<SomeColors> collection2 = new 
                ObservableCollection<SomeColors>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeColors)).Cast<SomeColors>());
            comboBox.ItemsSource = collection2;            
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Source = listBox;
            bind.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Color");
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
           comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, bind);
        ...`
Binding works

Comment: Binding works fine, but Listbox displaying not updated. I changed `public class TestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged` but it is not helped.

Comment: @Bush, there's a small example of implementing property notification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. I have edit my code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfBinding {
    public class TestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged{
        SomeColors color;

        public TestItem(SomeColors color) {
            Color = color;
        }
        public SomeColors Color {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Color");
                 }
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return Color.ToString();
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(String name) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != temp) {
                temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfBinding {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Data for listbox
            TestItem[] items = new TestItem[] {
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Green), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Green), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Blue), 
                new TestItem(SomeColors.Red), 
            };
            // Create ObservableCollection item
            ObservableCollection<TestItem> collection = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>(items);
            listBox.ItemsSource = collection;// set data for listbox

            ObservableCollection<SomeColors> collection2 = new 
                ObservableCollection<SomeColors>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeColors)).Cast<SomeColors>());
            comboBox.ItemsSource = collection2; // Get items from my enum
            // Create bindings
            Binding bind = new Binding();
            bind.Source = listBox;
            bind.Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem.Color");
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
           comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, bind);
        }
    }
}
```

Look Screen, please:
[image]

Comment: Thank you all! This problem solwed too: `listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Color";`.